# C++: Multiple Policies calling each other

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, policy

For a policy-based class-design I need some of the policies to call functions that are found in other policies:

```
struct PolicyA {
  void foo() {
    // ...
  }
};

struct PolicyB {
  void bar() {
    // Need to call foo() here
  }
};

template <class A, class B> MyClass : A, B {};
```

The two options I see are:

- Pass `MyClass<A, B>` to `PolicyA` and `PolicyB` as template parameters and do something like `dynamic_cast<MyClass<A, B>*>(this)->foo();`. However this may easily get very complicated (especially if it's not only `B` calling `A` but also the other way).
- Have a base class for each policy where all the functions are declared as pure virtual. This fails when one of the function needs its own template parameters, since virtual template functions are not possible.

This should be a common problem, but I didn't find anything. I guess there probably is some boost-magic or something. How would you solve this?

**Edit:** See also the followup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8334926/220918).

Comment: Do your policy classes contain any member variables that would be affected by the invocation of their member functions?

Comment: Redesign. If the policies need to know of each other, they're not independent policies.

Comment: yes, they do, unfortunately ;)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Are you sure this is generally a bad pattern? It seems like something very simple that could occur very often…

Comment: @lucasclemente: You can see why it's inelegant :-) How about making an intermediate policy that inherits both `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't `PolicyB` encapsulate `PolicyA` and call it as it needs? `PolicyB` is obviously aware of `PolicyA` - no need for base classes or inheritance.

It seems like all of your `Policy` implementations have some common `apply` method that outside callers can agree upon?

*Edit:*

Right, so if it's not just a simple case of one particular Policy implementation needing access to another, you should probably focus on creating a single interface for `Policy` - perhaps even a `Rule` class that can be composed together to form a particular `Policy` - see the Specification pattern.

```
class Rule {
    allows(Foo foo);
}

class Policy {
    Rule rule = new NotNullRule().and(someOtherRule);

    void applyTo(Foo foo) {
        if (rule.allows(foo)) {
            return foo;
        }
        foo.disable();
    }
}
```

Call them whatever you want, `Condition`, `Rule`, `Specification` - they're useful for assembling pieces of logic together in a manner that doesn't depend on them. Then when someone is looking at PolicyA they can see, clearly, the rules/conditions that govern its behavior, objectified.

Once you have policy implementations in place, if you need to enforce several policies on something, you can use the composite pattern again so that external classes only see a `Policy` interface. But again, you have a clear 'named' policies that are being referred to, not just cross-calling functions.

Comment: Encapsulating doesn't work if I want both policies to be able to call each other. But as KerrekSB noted in the comments, maybe this ist just bad design. I'll think about it…

Comment: @lucasclemente: If you like, you can post some details of what you're trying to do. Maybe a minimal, representative example. Then we can think of alternative solutions.

Comment: Hm, I thought about it and figured out some way to design it in a nicer way. Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Didn't quite work out the way I thought it would. I've posted a followup here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8334926/220918