# C++ Policy design with dependencies

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, policies

This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8326328/220918) question.

Basically I want a container that stores objects and later does something with them. I want to put both, the action performed on the objects (`ActionPolicy`), and the storage (`StoragePolicy`), into policy classes. At the end, there should be two functions on the class:

- `addObject()` with a signature depending on `ActionPolicy`, i.e. this function should be defined in there.
- `execute()`, which goes over all of the objects stored by `StoragePolicy` and executes `ActionPolicy::evaluate(obj)` on all of them.

In (partially pseudo-)code (the places marked with `Here` are the ones that don't work in this design):

```
struct ActionPolicy {
  // Signature is dependant on this policy
  void addObject(T obj, /* ... */) {
    // Do something with the object
    StoragePolicy::store(obj); // <--- Here
  }

  void eval(T obj) {
    // Do something with the object
  }
};

struct StoragePolicySingle {
  T obj;

  void store(T obj) {
    this->obj = obj;
  }

  void execute() {
    ActionPolicy::execute(obj); // <--- Here
  }
};


struct StoragePolicyMulti {
  std::vector<T> vec;

  void store(T obj) {
    vec.push_back(obj´);
  }

  void execute() {
    for (obj in vec) {
      ActionPolicy::execute(obj); // <--- Here
    }
  }
};

template <class A, class B> MyClass : public A, public B {
  // ...
};
```

All of this is performance-critical, so I can't just use a vector with one entry instead of `StoragePolicySingle`.

How would you solve this? Any pattern I'm missing?

Comment: If `execute` is one-by-one, then you make the main class dispatch the call (`exectute(data_begin(), data_end());`). If `exectute` has to know about the entire range, then make the action policy inherit from the storage policy.

Comment: Are the things `ActionPolicy` does with an object in `AddObject` and `eval` dependent on each other, or some shared state? If not, maybe separating into an `AddPolicy` and an `EvalPolicy` will help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Why does `ActionPolicy` need to know about `StoragePolicy`?

Why does an `ActionPolicy` have objects added to it?

If you pass the `ActionPolicy` to the `StoragePolicy` as an argument to `execute`, then call `eval` on either the single item or the collection, does this not solve it for you?

Comment: As I wrote `ActionPolicy` does some things with the object before it can be stored (it does not store the object). Also the signature of the `addObject` function should depend on which `ActionPolicy` one chooses. Do you mean passing `ActionPolicy` as template parameter? I thought about that, but somehow this doesn't look like the best pattern…

Comment: What about a seperate ActionPolicy member of the StoragePolicy, eval called pre-store. At least then the ActionPolicy exists solely to act on an object, and the storage policy stores an object. Then pass ActionPolicy to execute on the Storage, which would be a different action. To paraphrase, why does a single action policy need to know about the 'addObject' logic *and* the 'eval' logic? Why can't those be two separate things?